# How to move one folder back in Putty

Tags: putty

I'm new to Putty and I have installed this on Windows.

I need to move one folder back (one folder upper) from current directory.

I tried `cd..` and `cd...` but didn't work out.

So how to move one folder back from this directory to an upper folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to go to an upper directory use this command :

```
cd ..
```